# Sorting the VARCHAR field in numeric(with padding zeros)

Tags: shell-script, sort

I have data in my file like following

```
07020,6880A98805,03/09/2014
04374,6880698805,09/01/2014
05019,6880698805,07/01/2014
05020,2710239905,08/02/2007
05020,2710239905,08/31/2007
05021,2710239905,09/01/2007
05806,2710239905,08/30/2007
05807,8803975905,08/01/2014
05808,8803975905,06/01/2014
06019,6880698805,07/01/2006
06020,6880698805,03/09/2014
07807,8803975905,08/01/2014
13375,3470566899,07/16/2015
13376,3470566899,08/16/2016
058030,6880698805,01/12/201
058030,6880698805,01/12/2015
058030,6880698805,01/12/2015
100004,8803975905,03/09/2014
100005,8803975905,01/01/2015
100006,8803975905,02/01/2015
100007,8626833130,01/16/2016
100031,8803975905,01/12/2015
100031,8803975905,01/12/2015
100031,8803975905,01/12/2015
100032,8803975905,01/01/2015
```

I want to sort the file order by first field (numerically) and then second field (numerically) and then third.

Using the forums I tried several but somehow I am not getting the required order by using:

```
sort -n -t',' -k1.1n,1.15n -k2.1n,2.10n -k3.7n,3.10n -k3.1n,3.2n -k3.4n,3.5n <file_name.csv>
```

Can someone let me know, what is going wrong?

Comment: You have an `A` in the second field, so it's no longer numeric, which in turn means you shouldn't be using `-n` as part of the sort criteria for field 2.

Comment: There is a possibility that it can contain alphabets,but still i want the data to be sorted by numeric order(like order by in database).. Even If i am using sort -n -t',' -k1.1n ,1.15n  <file_name.csv> , this also not working as expected

Comment: You cannot (by definition) sort alphanumeric data numerically

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were pretty close. You can't sort the second field numerically, though, because it's not entirely numeric (there's an `A` in the first line).

This works for me:

```
sort -t, -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3.7,3.10 -k3.1,3.2n -k3.4,3.5n
```

Comment: Thanks roaima, seems this works for me..Let me work on some more sample data

Comment: @user206852 Please remember to accept this answer if it's the one that works best for you. That's how StackExchange sites work.